# SQL - Return rows where date range of current selection not overlaping previous selections

Tags: sql

I have a Vacation Slots table populated with available upcoming vacation dates.
We have a bidding process (Like NFL Draft Pick) where each employee gets to choose one of the available slots (RowNumber) starting with the most senior employee. Once all employees have made a choice, we start at the top of the seniority list and continue until all slots are picked. I need to query the Vacation Slots table after each pick and return only those rows that has either not been selected before or non-selected rows that do not conflict with the employee's previous selection. I am able to return all but the previous selections but I also need to prevent RowNum 2, 3 and 4 due to overlaping. [I have a SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc0ad/5) . Here is my code:

```
       CREATE TABLE VacationSlots
(EmpID int, RowNum int , StartDate date, EndDate date)
-- Seed with Vacation Slots
INSERT INTO VacationSlots (RowNum,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES (1,'2016-1-31','2016-2-28')
INSERT INTO VacationSlots (RowNum,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES (2,'2016-1-1','2016-1-31')
INSERT INTO VacationSlots (RowNum,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES (3,'2016-2-28','2016-3-15')
INSERT INTO VacationSlots (RowNum,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES (4,'2016-1-15','2016-2-15')
INSERT INTO VacationSlots (RowNum,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES (5,'2016-5-1','2016-5-15')
INSERT INTO VacationSlots (RowNum,StartDate,EndDate)
VALUES (6,'2016-6-1','2016-6-30')

-- Update with Employee Selections
UPDATE VacationSlots 
SET EmpID = 100 
WHERE RowNum = 1

UPDATE VacationSlots 
SET EmpID = 200
WHERE RowNum = 5
```

Here is my partial solution:

```
DECLARE @EmpID INT = 100
; WITH cte AS (
SELECT      
      v.RowNum,  v.StartDate, v.EndDate, v.EmpID
FROM
      VacationSlots v
WHERE 
        v.EmpID = @EmpID
        ) -- cte returns currently selecting employees previous selections.
          --Needed for comparison later

SELECT   
        s.RowNum, s.StartDate, s.EndDate

FROM 
        VacationSlots s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        cte on cte.Rownum = s.RowNum

WHERE   s.EmpID IS NULL-- This prevents returning  RowNum 1, & 5 - (Previously Selected)
    -- Here is where I am a bit lost.
    -- Need to ALSO NOT return RowNum 2, 3, and 4 due to overlaping 
    -- between Previous Selection ( results of cte) and available dates.
    -- Could use a JOIN of some type with cte or where clause, not sure how.
    -- Only row 6 should be returned

    -- Rows returned = WHERE EmpID IS NULL
    -- AND No Overlaps between remaining rows and previously selected rows
    --WHERE EmpID = @EmpID
    -- So RowNum 6 would be returned because EmpID is null and it doesn't
    -- overlap with any other row where EmpID = 100
```

Comment: Added my answer. You may need to work a bit with overlapping definition by changing the `JOIN` condition, but you should work it out :-)

Comment: @Concider Me, I think there is a disconnect. I need the remaining dates that don't overlap with the already selected dates of the employee (@EmpID), which are what the cte returns. It looks like you might have filtered out the remaining dates that overlap with themselves. I don't see a comparison to what is in the cte for filtering. The idea is that an employee can't pick a vacation slot that overlaps with one they alredy picked or that someone else has picked. I have an update to the SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cf4d/1 I might be able to solve this on what you provided though.

Comment: What does "someone else has picked a vacation slot" means? That there is an `EmpID` filled? What does it mean in your data? Please **edit** your question stating what should the code actually do for a declared `@EmpID` at start and make a list out of it.

Comment: @Consider Me, It means (EmpID IS NULL). I have edited the SQL comments after the final WHERE clause to better explain this. Just to be clear, as each employee makes a choice, they can't choose a slot already chosen either by themselves or another employee, and they can't pick a slot that conflicts with a previous selection they made. We have 15 employees bidding on 54 slots and I want to have a product available to show them which slots are available for them when it is their turn to pick. Appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please see the attached SQL Fiddle. This should work for any number of already booked vacation slots for particular `EmpID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Modified the query after discussing the goal with you in comments.

This query is going to behave well even if you allow more than `1` vacation slot already booked by the particular employee you're running the query for. It uses a `NOT EXISTS` clause with overlap checking for **both sides**.

This is required to correctly handle cases of `Rownum = 8 or Rownum = 9` in my attached <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97d5a/7)</kbd>. Notice, that `EmpID = 100` already has `2` vacation slots booked. This query would work for any number of them.

```
DECLARE @EmpID INT = 100
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT      
        v.RowNum, v.StartDate, v.EndDate, v.EmpID
FROM
        VacationSlots v
WHERE 
        v.EmpID = @EmpID
) -- cte returns currently selecting employees previous selections. Needed for comparison  later
SELECT   
        s.RowNum, s.StartDate, s.EndDate
FROM 
        VacationSlots s
WHERE   
        s.EmpID IS NULL
        AND NOT EXISTS ( 
          SELECT  1 
          FROM    cte 
          WHERE   (
                  s.StartDate BETWEEN cte.StartDate AND cte.EndDate
                  OR s.EndDate BETWEEN cte.StartDate AND cte.EndDate
                  OR cte.StartDate BETWEEN s.StartDate AND s.EndDate
                  OR cte.EndDate BETWEEN s.StartDate AND s.EndDate
                  )
        )
```

Comment: Perfect! I got it done right under the wire. FWIW, Each employee can have more than one selection. Like in the NFL draft, once all employees get a pick, we start back at the top of the list for the second, third, etc pick until all slots are taken.

Comment: Great :) By the way, this can be done without using `CTE`, but you probably already know that :-)